# phpMyAdmin: what is the parameter null?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a new question, this time about the parameter null in phpMyAdmin.

I am creating a datebase where some registers must be "Not null" and anothers I guess that it doesn't matter since my work doesn't say anything, I mean, it not say Not Null but Null either.

For example, table student:

```
id - Primary Key|Int|Not Null|Auto increment
teacher_id - Int| Not Null
age - Int ////What I should click here?? to click Null or not?  /////
name - Varchar(30) | Not Null
reg_date - Datetime ////What I should click here?? to click Null or not?  /////
```

So, when I created the DB, for some registers I didn't click the checkbox Null trying to say NOT NULL but I cliked the checkbox trying to say "nothing".

The question is, what do you think that I should do with the parameters where my work doesn't say anything?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the column has no meaning in the `NULL` state, or should not be `NULL` because it's a required column, or required reference to another table, make it `NOT NULL`.

Otherwise, it doesn't really matter. Unless you need to store `NULL` values, it's somewhat arbitrary what you set.

Comment: Thanks tadman, I just wanted to be sure. And sorry if my question was A bit silly.

Comment: Asking questions and looking a bit silly is a lot better than not asking and doing something dumb.